# cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute {0} must appear on element {1}

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm new to xml and trying to validate xml with respective xsd but facing an error:

> cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'Companyname' must appear on element
>   'company'

Even though I already added Companyname in xml as well as xsd. What could be causing this error. Any help/suggestion?

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<company Companyname="abc" address="hj" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:SchemaLocation="companyxsd.xsd" >
    <department dname="dfsdf" deptphoneno="1232321" deptfaxno="2323" deptemail="fefsf">
        <employee empid="fsd" ename="fuehuf" emailid="fhueh" phoneno="364764"> </employee>
        <employee empid="fsd" ename="fuehuf" emailid="fhueh" phoneno="364764"> </employee>
        <contractEmployee name="fdsf" phoneno="12345"> </contractEmployee>
    </department>
</company>
```

**companyxsd.xsd:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
        <xs:element name="company" type="comType"/>
        <xs:complexType name="comType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="department" type="deptType"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="Companyname" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="address" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="deptType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="employee" type="empType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                    <xs:element name="contractEmployee" type="conType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="dname" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:integer" name="deptphoneno" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:integer" name="deptfaxno" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="deptemail" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="empType">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="empid" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="ename" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="emailid" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:integer" name="phoneno" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexType name="conType">
                <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="name" use="required"/>
                <xs:attribute type="xs:integer" name="phoneno" use="required"/>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

[ER DIAGRAM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qktkQ.png)

Comment: *What could be causing this error*: you're not validating the file you think you're validating.

Comment: How so? I don't understand.

Comment: Everything looks correct on the XML/XSD level, so human error is the most likely cause. How are you performing the validation? Are you referring to the correct file and not to a previous version by accident?

Comment: This is the exact same code I'm using. I'm so frusturated. :(

Comment: I take back what I said about everything looking OK on the XML level. There are a multitude of problems: end tags not matching start tags, etc. If you would be really validating this file, you would get different errors before you hit the `cvc-complex-type` error.

Comment: I fixed xml tags. But still the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML contains a number of errors. It is not well-formed (start tags not matching end tags) and contains a number of violations against your schema (`employee` and `contractEmployee` tags must be empty).

I've cleaned up your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<company Companyname="abc" address="hj" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <department dname="dfsdf" deptphoneno="1232321" deptfaxno="2323" deptemail="fefsf">
        <employee empid="fsd" ename="fuehuf" emailid="fhueh" phoneno="364764"/>
        <employee empid="fsd" ename="fuehuf" emailid="fhueh" phoneno="364764"/>
        <contractEmployee name="fdsf" phoneno="12345"/>
    </department>
</company>
```

This validates correctly against your schema, as can be tested e.g. on [this site](http://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation/#.WZVMOt8xBhE).

Any further problem you might have, are related to the way you perform the validation, and not to the XML or XSD contents.

Comment: I'm still having the same error in the platform I'm using. :( Actually i converted er diagram to xml and don't know if the error is becuase of this conversion. Can you have a look at the ER diagram I linked at the end of the question and tell if the xml is correct for that.

Comment: I can only repeat it so many times: the file that you *think* you are validating is not the file you are *actually* validating. If the XML that I prepared in my answer will not validate against the XSD that you provided, then there is something wrong with the way you perform the validation. Not with the XML, not with the XSD, and not with the ER diagram. Have you tried validating on the site that I linked to in my answer? Or any other only XML validation service?

Comment: The question is in one line to "generate xml and xsd for ER diagram". Now, I don't know what else I can do to solve it as question require two separate files for xml and xsd. :(

Comment: The XML I provided is correct, the XSD you provided is correct. The XML *will* correctly validate against the XSD. The ERD doesn't matter, so, based on the information you provided, I have no idea what the problem is you're facing.

Comment: ERD may matter because I'm trying to solve it on online platform which may have it's own test cases to evaluate. So when I click on evaluate I'm getting error (Attribute 'Companyname' must appear on element 'company'). Since the xml and xsd are correct, the problem may lie with ERD conversion.

Comment: The ERD is not involved in the XML validation.

Comment: Can you check like if Companyname is attribute and not child element in ERD?

Comment: The ERD does not dictate the semantics of the XSD or the XML. Whatever tool/platform you're using is doing that.